# DOM specified Property return true

Tags: javascript, dom

Someone told me if the attribute not defined, the specified value will return false. xms attribute did not have definition, but specified return true. What situation does specified return false?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button find out if the button has an onclick attribute specified.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()" class="" xms >Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0];
    var x = btn.getAttributeNode("onclick").specified;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

        var y = btn.getAttributeNode("class").specified;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;

        var z = btn.getAttributeNode("xms").specified;
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = z;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the attribute values and check if they are equal to `undefined`.

```
var x = btn.getAttributeNode("onclick");
if (x !== undefined)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

EDIT:
To check if node exists and it have a real value

```
var a = btn.getAttributeNode("xms").specified;
var b = btn.getAttributeNode("xms").nodeValue;
if (!a || a===undefined || b=='') //It's like false, because the node doesn't exists or its value is empty
```

Comment: The key problem is that z=true, however xms is not defined.

Comment: @AndyTang I think the problem is that it's not defined but it appears in button tag, so it exists, so its' true.
Maybe you should double-check it, so first check if it exists, then take its value and check if it's undefined or empty string. If it is, you should treat it like a false response.

`var a = btn.getAttributeNode("xms").specified;`

Answer (score 0):

I added 3 alert command and get the results as below.

```
var z = btn.getAttributeNode("xms").specified;
alert (btn.getAttributeNode("xms").nodeName);   //display xms
alert (btn.getAttributeNode("xms").nodeValue);   //display nothing
alert (btn.getAttributeNode("xms").innerHTML);    //display undefined
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `xms` is present in the tag then its considered as specified.

In fact, I think that DOM attributes in tags without values are by default considered boolean attributes with value of `true`, like the `hidden` or `checked` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> What situation does specified return false?

In browsers, never. The [DOM living standard states it explicitly](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-attr):

> readonly attribute boolean specified; // useless; always returns true

So what's it for? In other contexts, XML documents are accessed through the DOM API, and typically the DOM 3 spec applies here.

[DOM 3 says](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-637646024):

> If the attribute was not explicitly given a value in the instance document but has a default value provided by the schema associated with the document, an attribute node will be created with specified set to false.

So this is something related to XML schemas, where the attribute for the element has a default value.

In browsers, the `specified` property just exists for backward compatibility, because there are web pages which attempt to use the property and the JavaScript would break if it didn't return a true value.